# Jade: Serving route-specific resources

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In my `./inc/footer.jade` I have a bunch of script tags. I would like to serve additional script **only in one specific route.** How to accomplish this?

In controllers I could do:

```
res.render('someTemplate', {
  extraScript: true
});
```

and in footer.jade

```
- if (extraScript)
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
```

but then I would have to include this 'extraScript' variable in every single route (set to false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to check whether a variable exists.

```
- if (typeof extraScript !== 'undefined')
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
```

In this way, for all the routes that do not need the additional script, you simply don't pass in `extraScript`, and then in the template, `typeof extraScript !== undefined` will be evaluated to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The extraScript solution works, but I believe a better solution would be to use template inheritance (block and extends keywords) . This way you don't have to add logic and a local variable to your templates, and you can still keep things DRY in your jade markup.